# Fixing CSS table overflow and styled scrollbar [with JS Bin]

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to add scrolling for the table body but I can't get the header to line up with the columns.

I also want to position the scrollbar inside the table without covering any text in the cell.

Looking forward to seeing some genius at work. I'm beating my head against a wall.

[image]

Here's the code: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yuhuceyona/edit?html,css,js,output)

**CSS**

```
tr {
    width: 100%;
    height:20px;
    //table-layout: fixed;
}
table {
    height: 220px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
th, td {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables don't scroll. You have to put them inside a div that does.

The columns weren't lining up because of position:absolute on the tbody -- I think that was changing the tbody to a regular block-level div with a table inside it that was ultimately wrapped in a table cell.

Removed a bunch of other stuff from your css, like width:100% on tr. tr's are always width:100%.

Not sure what effect the width:50% on .fluid will have. Test it on windows wider than your table and narrower than your table to find out.

```css
table {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}

.fixed {
  min-width: 300px
}

.fluid {
  width: 50%;
}

#scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #D62929;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 200px; overflow-y:scroll" id=scrollbar>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="fluid">First Column</th>
        <th class="fixed">Fixed Column</th>
        <th class="fluid">Third Column</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>ads</td>
      <td>332113232</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted a fixed header with the scrollbar on the inside. I've figure out something patching some other code together. Small bug though.

Answer (score 0):

I've put the scrollbar in the table and fixed the header hacking div over a transparent header.

There's just 1 bug where the header text goes off the end of the table if resized too small. Otherwise looks good.

I didn't think something like this would be so difficult.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tohinevudo/1/edit?html,css,output) or run snippet below.

```css
html, body{
  padding:20;
  font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #b3d5d6;     /*outer border*/
  padding-top: 25px;             /*header height*/
  background: #b3d5d6;           /*header color*/
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 250px;                 /*table height*/
}
table {
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;    /*cell column seperator*/
}
td, th {
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;  /*cell row seperator*/
  color: #000;                   /*text color*/
  padding: 2px 10px;             /*cell padding*/
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {              /*alternate cell colors*/
  background: #FFFFFF; }
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F6FAFA; }
th {                             /*hidden header*/
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;                  /*header color*/
  padding: 5px 10px;            /*header alignment*/
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;  /*header column seperator*/
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
tr:hover td {
  background: linear-gradient(#91bbbc, #d6e6e6 5%, #d6e6e6 95%, #91bbbc);
}
.fixed {
 min-width: 200px;
}
.fluid {
 width: 50%;
}

#scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 8px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 background-color: #7997a1;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="container" id="scrollbar">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th class="fluid">
            First Column
            <div>First Column</div>
          </th>
          <th class="fixed">
            Fixed Column
            <div>Fixed Column</div>
          </th>
          <th class="fluid">
            Third Column
            <div>Third Column</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>        <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>ads</td>
            <td>332113232</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```